# Different ways to do a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on an old website and I've just found something strange. Www.mysite.com redirects to www.test.com, while mysite.com (non-www) redirects to www.other-site.com.

I've checked the htacces, and it only contains rules to redirect traffic to test.com. www.other-site.com is not present in the file. So how is it possible? Where should I check if there's a rule for this redirect?

Environment:
Centos server / 
Apache / 
Three sites are on different servers

Comment: You haven't provided any useful information. e.g. Are all these sites on the same server? Did you check the vhost files for redirects not just htaccess? is this using a control panel of any kind. Did you check if DNS is doing domain forwarding? There are tons of things and you haven't really given much info about your environment. Even though this is slightly off topic.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a DNS issue. If both www.test.com and test.com point to the same server then it is all server side. Virtual hosts can sometimes be the problem if you have Apache set that way then you will need a Virtual host for both www.test.com and test.com. I would say start with the DNS, then the apache config, then the site folder.

Hope that helps.

Comment: At the moment I don't have access to dns panel. How can i check if test.com and www.test.com point to the same server?